# Indexed summation and product

Tags: summation, products, index-notation

How do I expand these 2 formulas:
$$\Sigma_{s\in \{a,b\}}\Pi_{t\in \{c,d\}}x_{st}$$ and
$$\Pi_{t\in \{c,d\}}\Sigma_{s\in \{a,b\}}x_{st}$$
?

**EDIT:** **They should be the same !**
See $(6.29)$ and $(6.30)$ in the snippet below, but the are NOT.

$$x_{ac}x_{ad}+x_{bc}x_{bd}\quad (6.29)$$

$$(x_{ac}+x_{bc})\cdot(x_{ad}+x_{bd})\quad (6.30)$$

[image]

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: I got stuck right at the beginning :-(

Comment: I've deleted my answer (which was just a hint). Your 6.29 and 6.30 are right. I don't follow the argument from the book/article, but it does have an additional assumption: does that kill the cross terms?

Comment: @ancientmathematician I can send you the entire pdf to your email, if you give me one and you can check it in more detail.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I'm curious about this part of the book chapter $(6.29)$ and $(6.30)$ anyway.This sentence should be the key : "Equation $(6.30)$ follows from changing the order of the product and the summation andfrom the assumption that every path intersects every information set at most once."

Comment: That is the sentence I meant. I don't understand its algebraic significance.

Comment: Look [here](http://93.174.95.29/main/1161000/47cbd612cc702a8c4677a38623e532d3/Michael%20Maschler%2C%20Eilon%20Solan%2C%20Shmuel%20Zamir%20-%20Game%20Theory-Cambridge%20University%20Press%20%282013%29.pdf) on the page 229.